# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'bankDetails[0]' available as request attribute error in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here is my JSP code snippet which causes error

```
<form:select path="bankDetails[0].applicantType">
    <form:option value="Applicant">Applicant</form:option>
    <form:option value="Co-Applicant 1">Co-Applicant 1</form:option>
    <form:option value="Co-Applicant 2">Co-Applicant 2</form:option>
    <form:option value="Co-Applicant 3">Co-Applicant 3</form:option>
    <form:option value="Guarantor 1">Guarantor 1</form:option>
    <form:option value="Guarantor 2">Guarantor 2</form:option>
    <form:option value="Guarantor 3">Guarantor 3</form:option>
 </form:select>
```

Here is my controllers code

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "enterBankDetails.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView enterBankDetails() {
      functionName = "enterBankDetails";
      logger.info("In "+className+" - "+functionName+" ");
      BankDetails details = new BankDetails();
      ArrayList<EntityBankDetail> entitityBankDetails = new ArrayList<EntityBankDetail>();
      for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ;i++){
            EntityBankDetail entityBankDetail = new EntityBankDetail();
            entitityBankDetails.add(entityBankDetail);
      }
      details.setBankDetails(entitityBankDetails);
      return new ModelAndView("bankDetails/bankDetails", "command",details);
   }
```

Here is the bean code

```
public class BankDetails {
    private ArrayList<EntityBankDetail> bankDetails;
    private String[] entities;
    private int noOfBankDetails;
     private String test;
      //getter and setter methods
}

public class EntityBankDetail {
    private String nameOfBank;
    private String EMIforProposedLoan;
    private String nameOfBranch;
    private String city;
    private String accountType;
    private String accountNumber;
    private String applicantType;
           //getter and setter methods  
}
```

I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'bankDetails[0]' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
```

Please help. I cant figure out what wrong i am doing ?

EDIT : the same happens when i bind it to test

```
<form:select path="test">
    <form:option value="Applicant">Applicant</form:option>
    <form:option value="Co-Applicant 1">Co-Applicant 1</form:option>
    <form:option value="Co-Applicant 2">Co-Applicant 2</form:option>
    <form:option value="Co-Applicant 3">Co-Applicant 3</form:option>
    <form:option value="Guarantor 1">Guarantor 1</form:option>
    <form:option value="Guarantor 2">Guarantor 2</form:option>
    <form:option value="Guarantor 3">Guarantor 3</form:option>
    </form:select> 

Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'test' available as request attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `bankDetails` is not an array, so passing is as an array to the form bean will not work properly. I would use a standard JSTL for-each loop to loop through the `bankDetails ArrayList`. Also, you are not passing bankDetails to the JSP, but rather the object `details`. Also check that you have a getter for bankDetails in the BankDetails bean.

```
<c:forEach items="details.bankDetails" var="bankDetail">
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

Edit: have a look at what you are returning as ModelAndView parameters. You have specified that the bean name should be 'command'. Change that to the String or name 'details' or the bean that you are using in the view JSP.

Comment: I dont have to printout the values. i have to bind the properties of each EntityBankDetail object to form.

Comment: I know, but you are accessing bankDetails as an array; not an ArrayList.

Comment: I can always access it that way i have a working code which illustrates this. Please check my edit too.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I had included the

```
 <form:select path="test">
    <form:option value="Applicant">Applicant</form:option>
    <form:option value="Co-Applicant 1">Co-Applicant 1</form:option>
    <form:option value="Co-Applicant 2">Co-Applicant 2</form:option>
    <form:option value="Co-Applicant 3">Co-Applicant 3</form:option>
    <form:option value="Guarantor 1">Guarantor 1</form:option>
    <form:option value="Guarantor 2">Guarantor 2</form:option>
    <form:option value="Guarantor 3">Guarantor 3</form:option>
    </form:select>
```

outside of my `<form:form> </form:form>` tag . So now i know that examining jsp structure is equally important if i get such kind of error.